data science for economics textbook suggestion
I'm looking for a textbook for data science course in graduate economics degree program. It has to be based on Python and have a lot of examples. I'd appreciate any suggestions.
Naturally, the grad Econ degree curriculum already has statistics, regressions, time series, panel, machine learning, some programming with R and Stata; and a ton of Econ courses. So, I'm thinking that data science course should be like an application of what students already are supposed to know plus a good measure of data manipulation and visualization.
